# When is creating local variables in functions already better?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a total of 6 global variables, and I were to call them in a function.

If I were to call them each 3 times is it already better to create a local variable in the function, would it run the function faster?

I'm currently using each 20 times, so I'm guessing it's definitely better? I was looking at the network time in google chrome but I guess it's too small of a test because I always get 6-7ms.

I put the length of a table in a var, I was told that would run the 'for' instead of getting the length each time, better to store it in a local var to the function. And then I have 6 other variables that I assign to local vars in the function, is that the best practice? If so, when would you say it's better to declare a local var in a function, if I were to call that variable at least how many times?

Comment: Yes, keeping values closer in scope is always going to be faster. However, whether or not it has an impact on the performance of your code is an different question. Worry about it when you have performance problems. And in that case, I believe that other parts have a higher impact than variable resolution.

Comment: I agree with Felix. As *Donald Knuth* said : "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: [I'm not sure that's the case in practice.](http://jsperf.com/scoped-close-vs-deeper) That said, I'm not a fan of micro-benchmarks and the main point was "worry about micro performance improvements only when you have to" which I fully agree with.

Comment: related: [Creating local variable counterparts of global objects if used multiple times?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24418102/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If i were to call them each 3 times is it already better to create a local variable in the function, would it run the function faster?

Not to any perceptible degree.  The reason you should avoid global variables is because they can conflict with any 3rd party utilities you're running, can conflict with any plugins your browser is running, and frankly make the code harder to read.

If your function needs 6 variables, then create those variables inside of the function.

If you have 3 functions that all share the same 6 variables, then **you have an object that desperately would like to be created** -- refactor your code to reflect that.

So something like this:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3;

function f1(){
    //use a, b, and c
}

function f2(){
    //use a, b, and c
}
```

Would become something like this:

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    f1: function(){
       alert(this.a);
    },
    f2: function(){
       //use this.a, this.b, and this.c
    }
};
```

And of course if you want a, b, and c to be private to the object, you can get creative with closures:

```
var obj = (function(){
   var a = 1,
       b = 2,
       c = 3;
   return {
      f1: function(){
         alert(a);
      },
      f2: function(){
         //use a, b, and c
      }
   };
})();
```

Comment: +1 For object waiting to be created. Also, premature optimization is the root of all evil 97% of time :)

Comment: Hey and thanks so much for all your help! When you guys say premature optimization, do you mean that attempting to optimize from the beginning without having the full picture (i.e. all your code available) you are most likely setting yourself up for trouble in the future? Or is there a different meaning to it?

Comment: @Hate - essentially.  Basically you shouldn't try to guess at what will be slow, and make micro-optimizations based on that guess.  Just write your code using standard, best practices, and as you do so, optimize anything that turns out to be slow.

Comment: Thanks once again for everyone's help

Comment: Oh, one more quick question if you don't mind. I heard using Math.floor multiple times is ugly. In my function I'm calling it 20 times. I was wondering if it's best practice to var mfloor = Math.floor; and use that var instead? Thanks once again

Comment: @Hate - I wouldn't bother to Alias Math.floor.  I can't imagine it'd make a bit of difference.