# Creating local variable counterparts of global objects if used multiple times?

Tags: javascript

I recently read, that if a global object (i.e. document) is being called multiple times then it would increase performance of the JavaScript by encapsulating this object into a local variable.

For Example, this should technically run faster..

```
var doc = document;
var a = doc.getElementById("id1");
var b = doc.getElementById("id2");
var c = doc.getElementById("id3");
```

than this..

```
var a = document.getElementById("id1");
var b = document.getElementById("id2");
var c = document.getElementById("id3");
```

Does this performance increase remain true, even in high availability/offline capable web applications and single page applications? Will memory usage grow substantially by creating local variable counterparts of highly used global objects? Why?

Comment: A few questions.  What platforms are we talking about (V8, SpiderMonkey, Nashorn, Chakra)?  What is the execution context (executing in the global scope, in a local scope [if so, how deeply nested are we talking])?  How often is the lookup being run (do we need to disable JIT or do we not want to start measuring until it definitely has kicked in)?

Comment: doc and document are both of the same depth and scope in your code, so no savings there. it's when you cut down on function activation envelope properties that you reduce look-up overhead. what really saves time is caching a.b.c.d into x...

Comment: @dandavis: "doc and document are both of the same depth and scope in your code" --- how would you know that?

Comment: @zerkms: how do i know? because that's what the code says (i see no dots)...

Comment: @dandavis: `var foo = 42; (function() { var bar = foo; }());` --- do you see dots here? Are variables defined in the same scope?

Comment: @zerkms: no, but i do see a function with different scope wrapping one of the vars, an artifact not present in the OP...

Comment: @dandavis: could you accept that OP has only provided a piece of code without context? That helps if you provide only significant part of the code not all 10s of megabytes of JS when you ask a question you know.

Comment: @zerkms: i generally don't try to interpret or assume invisible things... if the question were asked with your code, my comment would be different.

Comment: @dandavis: well, currently you **are** assuming the OP has that code in the global scope. Also an important note - there are no `<script>` tags provided, how do you know the provided code is even JS that runs, not just an HTML? Is it another assumption?

Comment: @zerkms: sorry, i'm not sure what your point is, can you please explain my mistake?

Comment: @dandavis: your mistake is to state "both of the same depth and scope in your code" unconditionally. You're making assumptions they are in the same scope (but obviously you cannot know that). If a newbie will read your comment they may think that you're right. Whereas it's not the case.

Comment: related: [When is creating local variables in functions already better?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16885760/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the statement is technically correct (the name resolution would be faster if a variable is declared in a current scope so that the interpreter doesn't traverse up checking every parent scope) - it's not what you generally need to do.

That's it - the given "optimization" will not give and measurable difference but will make the code more tricky.

Also don't forget the 1st optimization rule: measure first - then optimize what is slow. Is it slow what you're trying to optimize? Nope. Then leave it as-is.

> Does this performance increase remain true, even in high availability/offline capable web applications and single page applications?

It remains "true" for every piece of code written in JS.

> Will memory usage grow substantially by creating local variable counterparts of highly used global objects?

Nope, it should be pretty close (you're only assigning references, the actual objects are not being copied).